# How to properly extract data from txt file

Tags: c++, file, error-handling, file-handling

Whenever I try to read my text files I got stream issues and extraction issues and cannot handle it properly on console output plus a lot of garbages.
Can anyone show me the right way to use the functions I have used in my code? I am a beginner.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

struct student {
    char rollnum[28];   //struct to store data
    char course[4];
    int md, ss, fn;
};
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("okhi.txt");   //file openning here
    if (fin)
    {

        student dat[21];
        string h1, h2;                //strigs to get 1st two lines as it is
        getline(fin, h1); fin.clear();
        getline(fin, h2); fin.clear();
        cout << h1 << endl << h2 << endl;

        for (int x = 0; x < 21; x++)
        {
            dat[x].md = dat[x].ss = dat[x].fn = 0;

        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 21; x++)
        {
            fin.getline(dat[x].rollnum, 28);
            cout << dat[x].rollnum;
            fin.clear();
            fin.getline(dat[x].course, 4);
            cout << " " << dat[x].course;
            fin.clear();
            fin >> dat[x].md;
            cout << " " << dat[x].md;
            fin >> dat[x].ss;
            cout << " " << dat[x].ss;
            fin >> dat[x].fn;
            cout << " " << dat[x].fn<<endl;
            fin.clear();
            fin.ignore();

        }
        cout << dat[0].rollnum << endl;
    }
}
```

[The text file i want to read & output m getting are shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtkN8.png)

Comment: Do not post images of text. What you want is output formatting using e.g. `std::setw(5)`.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Please show a sample of the input file.

Comment: Since you are a beginner and have `#include <string>`, use `std::string` in your structure instead of `char` arrays.

Comment: What do you expect to happend with `fin.clear()`?  The `clear` method clears the {error} state of the input stream.

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of arrays.  The `std::vector` can resize automatically and is a good choice when the input quantity is unknown at compile time.  For example, what happens when your input file contains 10 records?